# Rails 3: setting the timezone to the current users timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

I put this in Application Controller:

```
before_filter :set_timezone 

def set_timezone  
Time.zone = current_user.time_zone 
end
```

But I always get the error:

```
undefined method time_zone for #<User:0xa46e358>
```

and I just don't know why...

I hope someone can help

Comment: Why do you think this should work? current_user.time_zone

Comment: http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/1/25/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-easier-timezones

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Max -- the [ryandaigle.com article](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/1/25/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-easier-timezones) you mentioned links to [this writeup](http://mad.ly/2008/04/09/rails-21-time-zone-support-an-overview/) where you need to create a migration to add "time_zone" as an attribute to the user

(this is from the article, in rails 2.x syntax)

```
$ script/generate scaffold User name:string time_zone:string
$ rake db:migrate
```

later

```
<%= f.time_zone_select :time_zone, TimeZone.us_zones %>
```

That's why your .time_zone is returning a method_missing -- you haven't stored the time_zone on the user yet.

Comment: Is there a way to get the timezone from a user that is not in the database and is just visiting the site?

Comment: This might be helpful (get it in javascript)- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getTimezoneOffset.asp

Answer (score 27):

Further to Jesse's answer, I should add that you can generally avoid adding a new column in db and just create a custom method in user model and **make use of cookie** to get the user's 
timezone:

**in client-side (js):**

```
function set_time_zone_offset() {
    var current_time = new Date();
    $.cookie('time_zone', current_time.getTimezoneOffset());
}
```

**in Application Controller:**

```
before_filter :set_timezone 

def set_timezone  
 min = request.cookies["time_zone"].to_i
 Time.zone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone[-min.minutes]
end
```

Comment: +1 for trying to determine the timezone from information available without user explicitly providing it. This is a rather unreliable method of doing this, though. In a production environment you would want to use something [like this](https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect/src/ab0cfa941246/detect_timezone.js) to detect the timezone more accurately, and you should always store this and allow the user to override it.

Comment: Using cookies its work perfect but what we can do if someone clear cookies or not allow to cookies then?

Answer (score 2):

```
function set_time_zone_offset() {
  var current_time = new Date();
  $.cookie('time_zone', current_time.getTimezoneOffset());
}
```

This is not correct, because time offset is not constant, it depends on daylight saving time periods.
Rails expects the standard time offset when calling **ActiveSupport::TimeZone[-min.minutes]**.

ex: in France at date 09/03/2013 10:50:12 +02:00, your javascript will return -120 as offset where ActiveSupport will need -60 to resolve France timezone.

Then you need to check if this is a [daylight saving time period in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11888430) then if this is the case you will have to substract one hour to the offset to get the right value used by Rails.