# Time object in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to know if Time.localtime returns the user local time or the server local time.

If it is the server, is it any clean way to convert a UTC time or datetime to user local time?

Comment: It returns the time of the machine it's running on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby's `Time` class knows nothing about any "client". You would have to inspect request headers for that. [`Time#getutc`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-getutc) and [`Time#getlocal`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-getlocal) seem to be what you want. Notice the variant on `getlocal` where you can enter the TZ offset - if you pass it the client's TZ, you can get the client's local time. As I said earlier, you would have to look into the request headers to figure out which TZ it is.

EDIT: Scratch that, apparently there does not have to be a Date header in a request. So you're down to [JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269270/rails-3-setting-the-timezone-to-the-current-users-timezone) to tell you about the time zone.

Comment: Ok so there is not an automatic ruby function that looks into the request headers and convert into client's time, right?

My hope was that Time.getLocal would look into the request header.

Comment: `Time` class doesn't know anything about HTTP. It's a time class. Ruby is not implicitly a web language like PHP is, where you might expect everything to bend one ear towards the web server.