# Ruby on Rails Time.zone.now

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-1.9.2

I am using Time.zone.now to get the user's time.

I think that this is wrong. Can you confirm that it is wrong? How can I get the user's time?

Who is setting Time.zone on my server?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269270/rails-3-setting-the-timezone-to-the-current-users-timezone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is wrong. Time.zone is whatever your application's timezone is set to. This is usually set in application.rb

```
config.time_zone = 'UTC'
```

If you want a user's timezone, you'll need to either get it from the client side via JavaScript or let the user set it themselves in your application.

Comment: I have config.time_zone = "Pacific Time (US & Canada)" in my timezone but if I print Time.zone in a page it is showing my real timezone (which is not Pacific time), why?