# undefined local variable or method `set_timezone' for controller error in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, timezone

I'm setting a timezone for the users using  `ENV["TZ"] = time_zone` where time_zone is that user time zone.I also have a column in table named `'time_zone'` where that user's timezone is saved.
 Now i want to retrieve the event of that users in his time zone. 
To retrieve my code in the model:

```
  def set_timezone
   Time.zone = current_user.time_zone || "Asia/Kolkata"
  end
```

My controller:

```
before_filter :set_timezone
```

But i'm getting this error `undefined local variable or method 'set_timezone' for SchedulersController:0x533fa78` 
Any Idea what could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also pass a closure/block as an argument to `before_filter`, like this:

```
before_filter do
  Time.zone = current_user.time_zone || "Asia/Kolkata"
end
```

Comment: Nope, it's a controller behavior :)

Comment: Now i'm getting undefined method timezone

Comment: Did you mean `current_user.time_zone`?

Comment: This "undefined method `time_zone' for #<User:0x5327520>"

Comment: Your should define this method or property in your `User` model

Comment: I think you want keep `User`'s time_zone as a persistent property, so add it in your migration that creates user fields in database, it will automatically add setter/getter methods to your model.

Comment: Managing timezone is spinning my head is there any material or notes i can refer to?

Comment: I found a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269270/rails-3-setting-the-timezone-to-the-current-users-timezone

Comment: And you also can read this article: http://databasically.com/2010/10/22/what-time-is-it-or-handling-timezones-in-rails/